# Is it possible to start a React application from within a Visual Studio Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

See question. I am working within a Visual Studio Code extension that uses the Webview API. I've been searching for any method but can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should be possible. After generating the production build you can load the main page into a Webview and it should work just like in a browser. You have to ship the production build with your extension, of course.

Comment: What I have done in the past is created a react app within the same project as my extension, ran the app which opens to the browser, then opened to the same browser in my extension using vscode.env.openExternal(). Is this what you mean? I was hoping for a way to start the react app directly from my extension.

Comment: Just to clarify, I want the react app to render to the browser.